# Why does Android Realm return no results when synced with MongoDb?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using Android Realm with sync, and when I do a basic query, it returns no items.

sync is enabled in build.gradle using:

```
realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}
```

In my fragment (irrelevant bits removed):

```
private var adapter: MenuRealmAdapter? = null
private var realm: Realm? = null
private var menuItems: RealmResults<MenuItem>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        realm = App.mongoProxy.getSyncRealm()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_list, container, false)
        buildAdapter(view, RealmFacade.shared.emptyMenu as RealmResults<IListItem>)
        buildMainMenu()
        return view
}

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        menuItems?.removeAllChangeListeners()
        realm?.close()
}

private fun buildMainMenu() {
        menuItems = realm?.where<MenuItem>()?.findAllAsync()
        menuItems?.addChangeListener{ items ->
            // items is empty here //
            adapter?.updateData(items as OrderedRealmCollection<IListItem>)
        }
}

private fun buildAdapter(view: View, menuItems: OrderedRealmCollection<IListItem>) {
        adapter = MenuRealmAdapter(menuItems, mListener, true)
        val realmRecyclerView = binding!!.realmRecyclerView
        realmRecyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
        realmRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

MongoProxy.kt:

```
fun getSyncRealm (userPartition: Boolean = false): Realm? {

        val user = app.currentUser() ?: return null
        val partitionValue = getPartitionValue(userPartition)
        Log.d(TAG,  "Get realm for userPartition: $userPartition value: $partitionValue")
        val config = SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, partitionValue)
            .waitForInitialRemoteData()
            .build()
        return Realm.getInstance(config)
}
```

I have this working on iOS without issue, so I know the data and rules are set up fine, and the partition value gives me a sensible value, so I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

facepalm moment - I had turned off sync to compact the database and forgot to turn it back on XD